# Chart.js and scrollbars

Tags: javascript, charts

I am not having any luck getting chart.js to show scrollbars.
Is this even supported? Not specified in the documentations anywhere...

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-creating-a-chart-with-options

Comment: What exactly do you expect by `getting chart.js to show scrollbars`? Why not put your chart inside a `div` with fixed width / height and set `overflow:scroll` on `div`? Any issue with that?

Comment: What i need to make sure is when the amount of data is more than the size of the chart, that the scrollbars show up and the user can scroll. 
Have never done that using your suggestion. Does your suggestion allow for that?

Comment: Additionally, our 0,0 is at the right of the control as opposed to left, consequently, the scrolling will have to go from right to left